# Get CoreData Attributes for the UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, count

I use CoreData to Save Strings and present it in a UITableView. My problem is that I have more than one attribute in my entity and when I return the entity from the CoreData it counts all of the attributes in the function, and I want to get the first attribute (name: title) and return it with the count.

How can I get it?

Thanks for your help :)

```
var book = [Book] ()  `

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return book.count
}
```

Get func:

```
var mgdContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

func loadBook () { 
   let LoadRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book") 
   book = try! mgdContext.executeFetchRequest(LoadRequest) as! [Book] 
}
```

Comment: What dose your fetch look like?

Comment: `    var mgdContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    
    func loadBook () {
        let LoadRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Book")
        book = try! mgdContext.executeFetchRequest(LoadRequest) as! [Book]
    }

    `

Comment: Always edit your question and place code in the question. I have edited the question. To reflect the correct layout.

Comment: Why can't you say something like `let bookTitle = book[0].title`?

Comment: `tableView(tableView:, numberOfRowsInSection:) -> Int` has nothing to do with any specific attribute of the `Book` entity. It is only concerned with how many rows the specified sections should have. If there are ten books in the `book` array (should really be `books`) then the count should be `10` wether there are 100 or 2 attributes in the `Book` entity. If you are having issues with titles being displayed in the cells look in `tableView(tableView:, cellForRowAtIndexPath:) -> UITableViewCell`.

Comment: the Problem is that i need only the title for the numberOfRowsInSection because when i import a foto to the Book entity it´s make a new cell in the UITableViewCell, thats is that why i need the title to get the cell count for UITableView.

Comment: @beyowulf thats right that must run but how i can make that with count i have tried with `return (book[0].title?.count)!` it´s comes an error  'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion. How i can make it with count the title ?

Comment: Arrays have a count property in swift. Strings do not. book[0].title will give you the title of the first book in the array. Saying book[0].title.count makes no sense because you are asking for the count of the title. In swift, you are allowed to return a tuple, which is more than one value. I suppose you could declare a function that returns a type of (String?,Int) at the end of which you could say `return (book[0].title?, book.count)` Why that would be of use to you is beyond me.